# Trying to find majority element in a list

Tags: python, arrays, hash, hashcode

I'm writing a function to find a majority in a Python list.

Thinking that if I can write a hash function that can map every element to a single slot in the new array or to a unique identifier, perhaps for a dictionary, that should be the best and it should be undoable. I am not sure how to progress. My hash function is obviously useless, any tips on what I can/should do, or if this is even a reasonable approach?

```
def find_majority(k):
    def hash_it(q):
        return q

    map_of = [0]*len(k)

    for i in k:
        mapped_to = hash_it(i) #hash function
        map_of[mapped_to]+=1


find_majority([1,2,3,4,3,3,2,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,6,5])
```

Comment: You probably want to use a dictionary instead of a hand-rolled hash function in Python -- the language very much discourages you from doing this kind of thing.

Comment: do you want find the most common element or the major element (more than N/2 occurrences)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your approach is to use another array as big as `k` as your "hash map". If `k` is huge but the number of unique elements is not so huge, you would be wasting a lot of space. Furthermore, to find the majority, you would have to loop through your `map_of` hashmap/array to find the max.

On the other hand, a dictionary/set (where hashing is not your concern, and the underlying array structure will probably be more compact for average cases) seems a little more appropriate. Needless to say, with the occurring elements as keys and their occurrences as values, you can find what you want in one single iteration.

So, something like:

```
def find_majority(k):
    myMap = {}
    maximum = ( '', 0 ) # (occurring element, occurrences)
    for n in k:
        if n in myMap: myMap[n] += 1
        else: myMap[n] = 1

        # Keep track of maximum on the go
        if myMap[n] > maximum[1]: maximum = (n,myMap[n])

    return maximum
```

And as expected, we get what we want.

```
>>> find_majority([1,2,3,4,3,3,2,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,6,5])
(3, 5)
```

Of course, Counters and other cool modules will let you do what you want in finer syntax.

Comment: Yeah! I actually just solved it with a dictionary in a very similar manner = ) !

Answer (score 44):

Python has a built-in class called `Counter` that will do this for you.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter([1,2,3,4,3,3,2,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,6,5])
>>> c.most_common()
[(3, 5), (2, 4), (4, 4), (1, 3), (5, 3), (6, 2)]
>>> value, count = c.most_common()[0]
>>> print value
3
```

See the docs.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: use `c.most_common(1)[0]` -- `max()` vs. `sort()`.

Comment: Except that you will still need to check for ties yourself.

Answer (score 13):

There is an easy way to realize like this

```
l = [1,2,3,4,3,3,2,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,6,5]
print(max(set(l), key = l.count)) # 3
```

Comment: This is really concise! Note that this takes O(`len(set(l))` * `len(l)`) time, because it's calling `l.count` (an O(`len(l)`) operation) `len(set(l))` times, while we can do this in O(`len(l)`) time if we create a Counter beforehand.